# Galois group of the splitting field of $ x^6 - 5$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

$f  = x^6 - 5$ $\in \operatorname Q [x]$

I want to find a splitting field $\operatorname F$ of $f$ over $ \operatorname Q$

$\sqrt[6]{5}$ is a real root of $f$

$u$ is the 6-th root of unity

then $ \operatorname F= \operatorname Q( \sqrt[6]{5},u)$

f  = x^6 - 5 is irreducible for Eisenstein's criterion, $\operatorname{char} \operatorname Q=0$  $\Rightarrow$ f is separable    ⇒ F is a splitting field over $ \operatorname Q$  of a separable polynomial.
⇒ $\operatorname{Gal}( \operatorname F/ \operatorname K)=(\operatorname F:\operatorname Q)$

I know that $ \operatorname (Q (\sqrt[6]{5}):\operatorname Q)=6$

How can I find the degree of $(\operatorname F : \operatorname Q (\sqrt[6]{5}))$? I would have said $3$ but it's wrong, the solution is $2$, why?

And generally, in these excercises, how can I find the degree of the minimal polynomial of the n-th root?

Comment: The 6th root of unity satisfies $x^6-1=0$, but that polynomial is not irreducible. Factor it into irreducibles, and see which one is the minimal polynomial for a primitive 6th root of unity.

Comment: $x^6-1=(x^3+1)(x^3-1)=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible, than the degree is $2$. Thank you, very helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

$x^3 -1$ is not irreducible! That's why the degree is 2.

Comment: Of course. I feel so stupid now, ahah! Thank you very much